# Setting a Grid RowDefinition height in Grid according to its content in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding, height, row

What I want to do (I actually don't know if it's possible) is to set the height of a given row according to its content:

< Grid.RowDefinitions>
 
< RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=aaa, Path=Height" />

< RowDefinition Height="*" />

< /Grid.RowDefinitions>

Assume that aaa is put into the row of the Grid.

Please note: I want my row to keep the height set at the very beginning.

Is that possible at all?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
```

should do what you want.

**EDIT**

What you could do is add an handler to your content's SizeChanged event. In that handler, set the grid's appropriate RowDefinition's height to the ActualHeight of the content and remove the handler:

```
grid.RowDefinitions[x].Height = new GridLength(((FrameworkElement)sender).ActualHeight, GridUnitType.Pixel);
content.SizeChanged -= content_SizeChanged;
```

I haven't tested it, but it should give you a good start. **EDIT** tested, it works. Maybe there's a better way to do it, but that's one way.

Comment: unfortunately my control might change its height (it could be expanded). However, I want the grid row height to remain as set at the beginning, thus Auto is not a good option (the row would be resized)

Comment: Yes with those prerequisites, my answer won't get the job done. I suggest you edit your question to include the need that the row keeps its initial height should its content's height change, it wasn't clear for me :)